# Don't understand these C++ box2d Errors

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, xcode, box2d

I've trying to get this C++ method to work in my iOS game.

```
-(b2Vec2) RayCheckWithInput:p1 andX:p2
{
    b2RayCastInput input;
    input.p1 = p1;
    input.p2 = p2;
    input.maxFraction = 1;

    //check every fixture of every body to find closest
    float closestFraction = 1; //start with end of line as p2
    b2Vec2 intersectionNormal(0,0);
    for (b2Body* b = self.world.world->GetBodyList(); b; b = b->GetNext()) {
        for (b2Fixture* f = b->GetFixtureList(); f; f = f->GetNext()) {

            b2RayCastOutput output;
            if ( ! f->RayCast( &output, input ) )
                continue;
            if ( output.fraction < closestFraction ) {
                closestFraction = output.fraction;
                intersectionNormal = output.normal;
            }
        }
    }

    b2Vec2 intersectionPoint = p1 + closestFraction * (p2 - p1);

    return intersectionPoint;
}
```

I know a fair bit about obj-c, but not C++. Here's a screen shot of the errors for that method it's showing.

[image]

Any help appreciated (in Chrome you can do right click and open image in new tab to see it better)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be more explicit with the variables passed into the Objective-C function.  You are passing without a type so it is not able to infer that it is actually a C++ type rather than an Objective-C type.

Try something like:

```
-(b2Vec2) RayCheckWithInput: (CPPTye*)p1 andX: (CPPTye*)p2
```

***Edit***: a quick check of the box2d docs says you need something like this:

```
-(b2Vec2) RayCheckWithInput: (b2Vec2)p1 andX: (b2Vec2)p2
```

***Edit 2***: Also worth noting that the Raycast function takes a third parameter `childIndex` as described in the [docs](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/api-ref/1.0/Box2D/html/classb2_fixture.html#a614e84f47e8b32b503fa719099ecba79).

Comment: p1 and p2 are just vectors for points, not sure what type that would be in C++?

Comment: I'm not sure what the childIndex should be, but it's solved the errors, thanks :)